# How to create a shared pointer to a managed string?

Tags: c++, stl, visual-studio-2012

I would like to use a shared pointer for a managed string, but I cannot figure out the syntax.  To create the shared pointer, I need an allocator to call `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(managedString)`.  To free the pointer, the custom deletor should call `Marshal::FreeHGlobal`.  I'm looking for something like:

```
std::shared_ptr<IntPtr> managedFilename(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(videoFilename), 
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal);  // does not compile
```

The compiler is choking on the `videoFilename` parameter and an `IntPtr`-to-void conversion.

I have this working in conventional C; however, I want to use the STL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is result do you want to achieve?

If you want to use the string in unmanaged code, you have to write something like this

```
void MarshalString ( String ^ s, std::string& os ) {
    using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
    const char* chars = 
    (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
    os = chars;
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
}
```

If you are writing managed code, use a String^ type directly.

shared_ptr is not intended for use with managed types

**UPD**
You can do so like this, but why?

```
static void MyFreeHGlobal(void * ptr)
{
    using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(System::IntPtr(ptr));
}

// ...
System::String ^ s = L"test";
using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
boost::shared_ptr<void> managedFilename(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s).ToPointer(), 
    &MyFreeHGlobal);
```

Comment: I'm passing a managed string to native code.  I believe I have to use the `Marshal` class to convert a string (from C#) to a C++ `const char*`.  If there's a better way, I certainly open to it.  If not, I will use this approach.  Basically, I want to make sure there are no memory leaks when I convert to a `const char *`.